# Qt - serial port name in ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, serial-port, qtserialport

I have a problem with finding the serial port name on Ubuntu. As you know, for reading serial port on Windows, we can use this code for example:

```
serial->setPortName("com3");
```

but when I compile this code on Ubuntu, I can't use this code:

```
serial->setPortName("/dev/ttyACM0");
```

I know that my serial port name is ttyACM0 and I can read data on it by issuing this command:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

but why cannot I use this name in my code? What should I do?

Comment: Call errorString to see the problem, also try to use QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts to get list of all ports in system.

Comment: I do use QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts too. but it's not working! It works perfectly in windows but not here!

Comment: Do you have the permission to open the serial port?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get permission for your regular user, please get your sysadmin add to the group that is in charge of the serial ports like that emulated over usb.

It is either `tty`, `uucp` or something. It varies from distribution to distribution, but you can easily check this by running the following command:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
```

Then check the group column and get the sysadmin do this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G group username
```

Please do ***not*** introduce security vulnerabilities by giving global write access to others like this:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
serial->setPortName("ttyACM0");
```

Comment: What name `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()` returns for that port?

Comment: as i told 'ttyACM0' . I'm sure my serial port name is ttyACM0 but I really don't know why I can't set it!!!

Comment: Have you tried to construct `QSerialPort` using `QSerialPortInfo`?

Comment: Use [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qserialport.html#QSerialPort-3) constructor.

Comment: I left the micro that sends data from serial port in office but this constructor looks logical I hope it works.

Comment: I tried this constructor and it didn't work for me too! I really don't know what should I do!